# Javascript callback function with one parameter

Tags: ajax, parameters, callback

I'm trying to get the result of a function (ajaxGetPreference, that contain an ajax call), my code:

```
highlight_pref = 0;
highlight_pref = ajaxGetPreference('highlight');
console.log(highlight_pref);`
```

I'm getting always 0. Should I do something like this (see below)? I saw ither similar question, I don't know how to do with the parameter 'highlight'

```
ajaxGetPreference(function() {

    console.log(highlight_pref);
});
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Hi SLaks. Thanks for your reply, but I don't get it. Can you please explain me in this case what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand?  You can only use the result in the callback.